# Is my answer correct for this Logical Analysis of Arguments?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

The question is:

If U is a subspace of V, then U is a subset of V, U contains the zero vector, and U is closed under addition. U is a subset of V, and if U is closed under addition then U contains the zero vector. Therefore, if U is closed under addition, it is a subspace of V.

I said that:

- p = U is a subspace of V
- q = U is a subset of V
- r = U contains the zero vector
- s = U is closed under addition

So Γ = {p->(q^r^s),q,(s->r)}, ρ = (s->p)

Therefore, a counter-example would be v(s)=T, v(p)=F, v(q)=T, and v(r)=T which means that the argument is not valid.

My issue is that when I read this question logically, I feel like it should be valid. Have I made a mistake or is my answer correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why this is confusing is that it is easy to misread the first premise as if it was a *definition* of "subspace". But it really isn't -- all it says that IF you already know something is a subspace, then such-and-such. It doesn't say that some that satisfies such-and-such is necessarily a subspace, and doesn't even guarantee that any subspaces exist at all.

Therefore the premises cannot ever allow you to conclude that anything is a subspace. If you find yourself in a world where they are true, then you can change the world by making $U$ not-a-subspace, and the premises will *still be true* after this change. Therefore they don't imply that $U$ is a subspace.

Comment: Thank you! I understand now.